# DateTime Conversion in Scala Spark with 24 hours format

Tags: scala, datetime, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I have formatted the timestamp in dataframe in following way.

```
var df_v_5 = df_v_4..withColumn("endTimeFormat", 
from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('DateTime), "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss"))
```

The output I am getting as

```
DateTime,value1,value2,endTimeFormat
2017-01-01T12:00:00.000+05:30,11,-14,01-01-2017 12:00:00
2017-01-01T13:00:00.000+05:30,110,13,01-01-2017 01:00:00
```

**Expected output :**

```
DateTime,value1,value2,endTimeFormat
2017-01-01T12:00:00.000+05:30,11,-14,01-01-2017 12:00:00
2017-01-01T13:00:00.000+05:30,110,13,01-01-2017 13:00:00
```

How can I convert this timestamp into 24 hours format?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
//Maybe try to make the hh to uppercase
val df = spark.sql("SELECT from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('01-01-2017 12:59:59', 'dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss'), 'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss')")

df.collect().foreach(println(_))

// result
[01-01-2017 00:59:59]
```